# OAuth1: What to send to the client when the user declines?

Tags: oauth

I'm implementing an OAuth (1) server and wonder what to return to the oauth client if the user declines the request. [RFC 5849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) does not seem to define the behavior in this case.

Did I miss it? If it's really not defined, what do servers do so that clients understand that authorization was denied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really not defined in the OAuth 1 spec.

The [OAuth wiki suggests](http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/12238543/ProblemReporting) using a `oauth_problem` parameter that describes the issue. In the case of a cancellation: `oauth_problem=permission_denied`.